# Drupal 7 Creating Full Page Custom Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to create a full page, custom module.  By this, I mean a module that is not wrapped into the main Drupal sites them.  Here is my code:

myapp.module:

```
function myapp_menu() 
{
 $result = array();
 $result['myapp/home'] = array(
  'title' => 'My App Title', // Title of our page
  'description'=> 'My App Web Site', // Description of our page
  'page callback' => 'myapp_function', 
  'access arguments' => array('access content'), // permission to access this page
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, // type of menu item
 );

 return $result;
}

function myapp_function(){      
  return theme('my_custom_template');
}       

function myapp_theme(){
  return array(
    'my_custom_template' => array(          
      'template' => 'myapp-page',
    ),
  );
}
```

myapp-page.tpl.php

```
Hello World
```

The problem is that, when the page is displayed, it is still kept within the main Drupal Sites main theme.  I would like to make this page its own, full page, site.  Can anyone help with doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack like this :

```
function myapp_function(){      
  print theme('my_custom_template');
  exit;
}
```

Also you can use declaration options listed in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7.x

> Parameters
>
> array $existing: An array of existing implementations that may be used
>   for override purposes. This is primarily useful for themes that may
>   wish to examine existing implementations to extract data (such as
>   arguments) so that it may properly register its own, higher priority
>   implementations.
>
> $type: Whether a theme, module, etc. is being processed. This is
>   primarily useful so that themes tell if they are the actual theme
>   being called or a parent theme. May be one of:
>
> 'module': A module is being checked for theme implementations.
>   'base_theme_engine': A theme engine is being checked for a theme that
>   is a parent of the actual theme being used. 'theme_engine': A theme
>   engine is being checked for the actual theme being used. 'base_theme':
>   A base theme is being checked for theme implementations. 'theme': The
>   actual theme in use is being checked. $theme: The actual name of
>   theme, module, etc. that is being being processed.
>
> $path: The directory path of the theme or module, so that it doesn't
>   need to be looked up.

Comment: Great this worked.  But, you mentioned that this is a "hack".  Is this frowned upon?  Or is there a less "hacky" method?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure , but you can also create another theme (custom) and case by url https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-do-i-change-a-theme-based-on-the-url , or try all options from hook_theme declaration. But the simply and efficient method is this hack